# Golang img from base64 ZgotmplZ

Tags: go, go-echo

So i try to put image in  from base64 but i'm gettin ZgotmplZ i try to 
use template.URL(s) like this:

```
e := echo.New()
funcMap := template.FuncMap{
    "safe": func(s string) template.URL {
        return template.URL(s)
    },
}
t := &Template{
    templates: template.Must(template.ParseGlob("C:/Projects/Golang/hello/resources/*.html")).Funcs(funcMap),
}
e.Renderer = t
e.GET("/", func(context echo.Context) error {
    return context.Render(http.StatusOK, "index.html", GetData())
})
```

and in template:

```
 <td rowspan="2"><img src="{{.Icon|safe}}"></td>
```

But while i exeute: go run
panic: template: index.html:34: function "safe" not defined
so what i do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template functions must be defined before the template is parsed.  To fix the error, create an empty template, set the functions and then parse the glob:

```
templates: template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(funcMap).ParseGlob("C:/Projects/Golang/hello/resources/*.html")),
```